# Statistical variable transformation

Tags: statistics

i'm preparing my statistics exam and I dont know how to solve the following exercice:

Let X be a Statistical variable having the following values: $x_1$,$x_1$,...$x_r$. It is known that $\overline{x}=4$ and $S_x=2$ (typical deviation). Let $Y=(X-1)^2$. How much is $\overline{y}$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^ry_i=\sum_{i=1}^r (x_i-1)^2=\sum_{i=1}^r\left[x_i^2+1-2x_i\right].
$$
and
$$
\sum_{i=1}^r (x_i-\bar{x})^2=\sum_{i=1}^r x_i^2-\frac{1}{r}\left(\sum_{i=1}^r x_i\right)^2
$$